# Re-install ubuntu 22.04 on encrypted LVM partitions

Tags: lvm, reinstall

I have an existing installation (Debian) using encrypted LVM partitions. I would like to re-use the same partitions to install Ubuntu (more precisely, format the / partition with the new system but keep the existing /home partition). Does the 22.04 Ubuntu installer handle this situation? If not, is there a recent tutorial on how to do this?

I understand that this question has been around for a while concerning older Ubuntu versions, so I'm looking for the most recent answer. Thanks!